# Creating a new UWP app gives odd gap at top of display

Tags: mobile, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 I create a new Universal app from the Blank template and then update the page to have a green background and show some text...

```
<Grid Background="Green">
    <TextBlock>Hello World!</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Run on a Windows 10 machine it works just fine, with the entire client area of the window being green. But when run on a physical phone or using one of the Visual Studio phone emulators it has an odd gap at the top...

[image]

My physical phone (Lumina 950 XL Version:10.0.14393) and the 10.0.14393 version and 10.0.10586 version phone emulators give the same odd gap.

As I have not changed anything except the color and adding a text block I cannot see it is something I have done. Surely the out-of-the-box UWP app should display correctly on a phone! How is this supposed to be fixed?

Comment: Does this gap appear in a Tablet simulator? or just phone?

Comment: Cannot see a tablet simulator. it appears on all the Mobile Emulator's and on a real physical phone. But works fine on a desktop app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because the default theme (in App.xaml) is set to "Light" in the template and your phone is set to "Dark" in the personalization settings. So what you are seeing is a white status bar with white content.

Set RequestedTheme=Dark if that's what you want, or remove that property to let the app adjust to your current theme to solve this.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Worked like a charm, removing the RequestedTheme entirely. I think that should be the default in a new project otherwise many people are going to  fall over this issue like myself. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the status bar. You may have it with a white background and foreground. Try removing it first.

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
}
```

Make sure you include the mobile SDK:

*Add Reference -> Windows Universal -> Extensions -> Microsoft Mobile Extension SDK.*